# Copying fields from joined table to another table?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, python-2.7, spatial-join

I'm trying to write a standalone script to copy the values from 6 fields in a feature class to another feature class based on a spatial join and name query. I am stuck at updating the values from the join table to my original table.

```
print "Importing modules..."
import sys, arcpy, traceback 

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\LVS\PECO\PECO\Python\Python\Script\test_code.gdb\GAS"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Local variables:
GFR = "GFR"
Parcel = "PECO_TaxParcels"
GFR_SpatialJoin = "C:\\Users\\aadeyemo\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default.gdb\\GFR_SpatialJoin"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("GFR", GFR)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("PECO_TaxParcels", Parcel)
# Process: Select Layer By Attribute
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(GFR, "NEW_SELECTION", "STREET_NAME 

IS NULL")

# Process: Spatial Join

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(GFR, Parcel, GFR_SpatialJoin, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL")

path_dict1 = {}

SC1 = arcpy.da.SearchCursor (GFR_SpatialJoin, ["TARGET_FID", "STHSNUM", "STSTNAME", "STSUFFIX", "STCITY", "STSTATE", "STZIP"])
for row in SC1:
   path_dict1[ row[0] ] = row[1]
   print SC1[1]
   print path_dict1
del row

ucursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(GFR, ["OBJECTID", "STREET_NUMBER", "STREET_NAME", "STREET_SUFFIX", "CITY", "STATE", "ZIP_CODE"])
for urow in ucursor:
   if path_dict1.has_key( urow[0]):
   urow[1] = path_dict1[0]
```

This currently returns a value of zero when i try to copy values.

Comment: Does manual attribute join show matching records?

Comment: Also what is GFR? Script should return an error, not zero. Are we seeing a full story?

Answer (score 2):

You can make your dictionary creation more efficient with list comprehension and you have forgotten to commit the changes to the row by using the cursor's updateRow method.  The key for the dictionary is incorrect in the line that is supposed to read the street name from the dictionary for the current row, since you used a key of 0 and not row[0].  The indentation in your last section is also incorrect.  At the end of your script revise the last two sections of code as shown below.

I have revised the code to create the dictionary to hold a list of the field values and update all of the fields in the matching row in a single pass of the cursor.  See my Blog on [Turbo Charging Data Manipulation with Python Cursors and Dictionaries](https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2014/11/08/turbo-charging-data-manipulation-with-python-cursors-and-dictionaries) for more ways to deal with dictionary/cursor matching.

```
path_dict1 = {r[0]:(r[1:]) for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(GFR_SpatialJoin, ["TARGET_FID", "STHSNUM", "STSTNAME", "STSUFFIX", "STCITY", "STSTATE", "STZIP"])}

fields = ["OBJECTID", "STREET_NUMBER", "STREET_NAME", "STREET_SUFFIX", "CITY", "STATE", "ZIP_CODE"]
ucursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(GFR, fields)
for urow in ucursor:
    keyValue = urow[0]
    if keyValue in path_dict1:
        for n in range (1,len(fields)):  
            urow[n] = valueDict[keyValue][n-1]
            ucursor.updateRow(urow)
```